# Prove that $\zeta^{a} = \zeta^{b}$ if and only if $o \left( \zeta \right) \mid a-b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

Show that for all complex roots of unity $\zeta$, and for integers $a$ and $b$,

$\zeta^{a} = \zeta^{b}$ if and only if $o \left( \zeta \right) \mid a-b$ and $1, \zeta, \zeta^{2}, ...,\zeta^{o\left(\zeta\right)-1}$ are all distinct, where $o(\zeta)$ denotes the order of $\zeta$.

My work so far:

I know that the order $n$ of an element of any group $G$ is an integer such that for $g \in \mathbf{G}| g^{n} =e$ where $e$ is the identity element. So obviously $n$ must be a factor of $a-b$. However, I am having trouble tying this into the distinctness of $1, \zeta, \zeta^{2}, ...,\zeta^{o\left(\zeta\right)-1}$.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: when does $n\mid a-b$ if $0\le a,b\le n-1$? (how big are multiples of $n$?)

Also, maybe you’re leaving the details out because it isn’t your main question, but it isn’t really “obvious” that the order divides $a-b$, although it is really easy to prove by looking at the long division of $a-b$ by the order.

Comment: Where is the $n-1$ coming from? Is that the order I am assuming?

Comment: You could take $n$ to be the order in your case. The fact I hint at is true in general, but that’s what you’ll apply it to in combination with the first part of your question.

Comment: So I have made some progress: 
If you let $m$ = the order of $\zeta$, then $mk=a-b$ for some integer $k$, which implies $a=mk+b$.
Then, $\zeta^{a} = \zeta^{mk+b}=\zeta^{b} \left(\zeta^{m}\right)^{k}=\zeta^{b}$. Is this closer?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is trying to prove. You assumed $m$ divides $a-b$? But why? It is true that $m|a-b$ if and only if $\zeta^a = \zeta^b$, that is the first part, so are you trying to prove that now, or is what you wrote related to the second part? Did you try the hint?

Comment: The way I understand the question both parts have to be proved, so I am trying to start with proving that the order of $\zeta$ divides $a-b$. Perhaps I am not understanding your hint.